# Bootstrap Calendar not modal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to make Bootstrap Calendar not modal?  I just want to always display it inside a simple div tag.

I got it to work fine, but I need it to always display.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: which Bootstrap calendar are your using?

Comment: http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/  Do you have another sugestion I might try?  Just beginning the project so I am not married to anything yet.

Comment: Have not tried it, but this one looks promising: http://ahmontero.github.io/bootstrap-calendar/